# OSM Buildings: On Polygon click show PopUp

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, geojson

I have implemented a map with osm buildins and I woild like to show a PopUp on click on a GeoJson Feature.
My code until now looks something like this:

```
var map = new OSMBuildings({
    container: "map",

    position: { latitude: 47.048, longitude: 15.48 },
    zoom: 8,
    attribution:
      '© Data <a href="https://openstreetmap.org/copyright/">OpenStreetMap</a> © Map <a href="https://mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a> © 3D <a href="https://osmbuildings.org/copyright/">OSM Buildings</a>',
  });

  map.addMapTiles("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png");

  var graphs = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: [
      {
        type: "Feature",
        geometry: {
          type: "Polygon",
          coordinates: [
            [
              [15.48112119395733, 47.04852350729907],
              [15.48112119395733, 47.04847050686],
              [15.4810072000742, 47.04847050686],
              [15.4810072000742, 47.04852350729907],
            ],
          ],
        },
        properties: {
          id: 1255,
          roofColor: "#c93c2e",
          wallColor: "#c93c2e",
          height: 200,
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  map.addGeoJSON(graphs);
```

I have seen in some examples that I could use the getTarget function, but this function is no more available in the version 4.1.1

Thanks in advance!